# Django: ValueError: cannot assign none on ForeignField when trying to create in clean fails

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to automatically create an instance of a model for a ForeignKey field when a form is submitted. Here's a simple toy website that illustrates the problem:

I have two models, Model1 and Model2. Model2 contains a ForeignKey to Model1. I want the user to be able to create an instance of Model2 by either specifically selecting an instance of Model1 to store in the ForeignKey, or by leaving that value blank and letting an instance of Model1 be automatically generated.

Here's what I feel like that code should look like. My models.py code is very straightforward:

```
# models.py
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator


class Model1(models.Model):

    # Note this field cannot be negative
    my_field1 = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])


class Model2(models.Model):
    # blank = True will make key_to_model1 not required on the form,
    # but since null = False, I will still require the ForeignKey
    # to be set in the database.
    related_model1 = models.ForeignKey(Model1, blank=True)

    # Note this field cannot be negative
    my_field2 = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
```

forms.py is a bit involved, but what's going on is quite straightforward. If Model2Form does not receive an instance of Model1, it tries to automatically create one in the clean method, validates it, and if it's valid, it saves it. If it's not valid, it raises an exception.

```
#forms.py
from django import forms
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

from .models import Model1, Model2


# A ModelForm used for validation purposes only.
class Model1Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Model1


class Model2Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Model2

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(Model2Form, self).clean()

        if not cleaned_data.get('related_model1', None):

            # Don't instantiate field2 if it doesn't exist.
            val = cleaned_data.get('my_field2', None)
            if not val:
                raise forms.ValidationError("My field must exist")

            # Generate a new instance of Model1 based on Model2's data
            new_model1 = Model1(my_field1=val)

            # validate the Model1 instance with a form form
            validation_form_data = model_to_dict(new_model1)
            validation_form = Model1Form(validation_form_data)

            if not validation_form.is_valid():
                raise forms.ValidationError("Could not create a proper instance of Model1.")

            # set the model1 instance to the related model and save it to the database.
            new_model1.save()
            cleaned_data['related_model1'] = new_model1

        return cleaned_data
```

However, this approach does not work. If I enter valid data into my form, it works fine. But, if I don't enter anything for the ForeignKey and put a negative value for the integer, I get a ValueError.

> Traceback: File
>   "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in
>   get_response
>     111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in
>   view
>     48.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in
>   dispatch
>     69.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs) File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in
>   post
>     172.         return super(BaseCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs) File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in
>   post
>     137.         if form.is_valid(): File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
>     124.         return self.is_bound and not bool(self.errors) File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in
>   _get_errors
>     115.             self.full_clean() File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in
>   full_clean
>     272.         self._post_clean() File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in
>   _post_clean
>     309.         self.instance = construct_instance(self, self.instance, opts.fields, opts.exclude) File
>   "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in
>   construct_instance
>     51.             f.save_form_data(instance, cleaned_data[f.name]) File
>   "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py"
>   in save_form_data
>     454.         setattr(instance, self.name, data) File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py"
>   in **set**
>     362.                                 (instance._meta.object_name, self.field.name))
>
> Exception Type: ValueError at /add/ Exception Value: Cannot assign
>   None: "Model2.related_model1" does not allow null values.

So, what's happening is that Django is catching my ValidationError and still creating an instance of Model2 even though validation fails.

I could fix this by overriding the _post_clean method to not create the instance of Model2 if there are errors. But, that solution is ugly. In particular, _post_clean's behavior is very helpful in general--In more complicated projects I need _post_clean to run for other reasons.

I could also allow the ForeignKey to be null but never set it to null in practice. But, again, that seems like a bad idea.

I could even set up a dummy Model1 that I use whenever validation on the attempted new Model1 fails, but that also seems hackish.

In general, I can think of lots of hacks to fix this, but I have no idea how to fix this in a reasonably clean, pythonic way.

Comment: Off the top of my head I think you may need to at least swap the save and cleaned_data assignment around (as in model1.save then related_model1 = model1)

Comment: Hi Jeff, Thanks for the quick reply! I think that that order shouldn't matter, since these variables are references and the model has already been validated, so save should never fail. Your order does seem more natural, though, so I will switch it. However, this code is never being reached when the bug is happening, so that's not the cause of the bug.

Comment: add the following line `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` to just before creating new_model1 and then you can run a line at a time (by using n) and the values of new_model1 to your terminal which is running django. I suspect something is going a bit wrong on the validation_form creation and checking if it is valid. [link to docs on pdb](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html)

Comment: You call `new_model.save()` instead of `new_model1.save()`?

Comment: Jonathan, Sorry about that. That's a typo that I introduced in an edit in response to Jeff's comment.

Comment: @Jeff, Thanks so much for your help. I don't think that's it, though. validation_form is being properly created and validated. It correctly finds that it is invalid (because the value that I'm entering is negative). The problem is that, after I fail to create an instance of Model1, Django goes on to try to create an instance of Model2 anyway--because that's how _post_clean works. Since the ForeignKey field is blank because I couldn't create a valid model, things fail. If you want, I could include whatever info from pdb that you'd like.

Comment: Why dont you do the validation for `new_model1 = Model1(my_field1=val)` in the view? by doing so, you can call the validator explicitly, and you can keep the clean for Model2 indeed "clean"

Comment: @karthikr, I'm sorry, but I'm not sure exactly what you mean.

Comment: In the view, create the object -  model1 = new Model1(request.POST) , and then assign it to Model2 and then validate the form

Comment: @karthikr, Thank you for your suggestion. Sorry if I'm misunderstanding. If I understand you correctly, then I think that this might require me to do a lot of form-handling on my own. For example, if I create a new instance of Model1 successfully, then I can either save it immediately or not save it until I make sure that Model2 was handled successfully by the form. If I save it immediately and just pass it to super in request.POST, then I save something that I don't want saved if there are errors in Model2Form--and the user will see the Model1 that should not have been created.

Comment: yes exactly. It is not a whole lot of handling. Trust me your code would be a lot more modular in this way

Comment: @karthikr, Thanks again. I've posted a solution that's based on yours, but it uses a separate form to handle the post data.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution that I think might be acceptable, based somewhat on karthikr's discussion in the comments. I'm definitely still open to alternatives.

The idea is to use logic in the view to choose between two forms to do validation: One form is the standard model form and one is the model form without the ForeignKey field.

So, my models.py is identical.

My forms.py has two Model2 forms... one extremely simple one and one without the ForeignKey field and with new logic to dynamically generate a new instance of Model1 for the ForeignKey. The new form's clean logic is just the clean logic that I used to put in my Model2Form:

```
#forms.py
from django import forms
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

from .models import Model1, Model2


# A ModelForm used for validation purposes only.
class Model1Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Model1


class Model2Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Model2

# This inherits from Model2Form so that any additional logic that I put in Model2Form
# will apply to it.
class Model2FormPrime(Model2Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Model2
        exclude = ('related_model1',)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(Model2Form, self).clean()

        if cleaned_data.get('related_model1', None):
            raise Exception('Huh? This should not happen...')

        # Don't instantiate field2 if it doesn't exist.
        val = cleaned_data.get('my_field2', None)
        if not val:
            raise forms.ValidationError("My field must exist")

        # Generate a new instance of Model1 based on Model2's data
        new_model1 = Model1(my_field1=val)

        # validate the Model1 instance with a form form
        validation_form_data = model_to_dict(new_model1)
        validation_form = Model1Form(validation_form_data)

        if not validation_form.is_valid():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Could not create a proper instance of Model1.")

        # set the Model1 instance to the related model and save it to the database.
        cleaned_data['related_model1'] = new_model1

        return cleaned_data

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Best to wait til save is called to save the instance of Model1
        # so that instances aren't created when the Model2Form is invalid
        self.cleaned_data['related_model1'].save()

        # Need to handle saving this way because otherwise related_model1 is excluded
        # from the save due to Meta.excludes
        instance = super(Model2FormPrime, self).save(False)
        instance.related_model1 = self.cleaned_data['related_model1']
        instance.save()

        return instance
```

And then my view logic uses one of the two forms to validate, depending on the post data. If it uses Model2FormPrime and validation fails, it will move the data and errors to a regular Model2Form to show the user:

```
# Create your views here.
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

from .forms import Model2Form, Model2FormPrime


class Model2CreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = Model2Form
    template_name = 'form_template.html'
    success_url = '/add/'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.POST.get('related_model', None):
            # Complete data can just be sent to the standard CreateView form
            return super(Model2CreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            # super does this, and I won't be calling super.
            self.object = None

            # use Model2FormPrime to validate the post data without the related model.
            validation_form = Model2FormPrime(request.POST)
            if validation_form.is_valid():
                return self.form_valid(validation_form)
            else:
                # Create a normal instance of Model2Form to be displayed to the user
                # Insantiate it with post data and validation_form's errors
                form = Model2Form(request.POST)
                form._errors = validation_form._errors
                return self.form_invalid(form)
```

This solution works, and it's quite flexible. I can add logic to my models and to the base Model2Form without worrying too much about breaking it or violating DRY.

It's slightly ugly, though, since it requires me to use two forms to essentially do the job of one, pass errors between forms. So, I'm definitely open to alternative solutions if anyone can suggest anything.

Comment: Thank you for the question and answer! We're facing exactly the same problem. We thought of a bunch of hackish solutions too. Yours seems to be quite elegant, we'll see if it works in our case. I wish that models had more meaningful names in your examples (e.g. Author/Book instead of Model1/Model2), because it's not easy to follow the logic. Anyway, thanks very much again!